# call multiple functions by order use ng-click, single click and pass the same variable to multiple functions angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ng-click cannot call googlesearch function and keywordsearch fuction.

How to call two functions ng-click???
i would like to know how to create the single click, but run two functions by order.

for example:

That is on single click first function(googlesearch) executes

and then second function(keywordsearch) executes respectively.

html

```
<div class="test" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <input tpye="text" ng-model="keyword"/>
   <button ng click="googlesearch(keyword);keywordsearch(keyword)">search</button>
  </div>
<div>
```

angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {

    $scope.googlesearch=function(keyword){
    alert("do the googlesearch 1 "+keyword);
  };

   $scope.keywordsearch=function(keyword){
    alert("do the keywordsearch 2 "+keyword);
  };


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the second function inside your first one,

```
$scope.googlesearch=function(keyword){
    alert("do the googlesearch 1 "+keyword);
    $scope.keywordsearch(keyword);
  };
```

Comment: you are right. but the alert does not appear in my website. how to see the result? such as print the running statement.

Comment: @HiPownedBi did you check browser console to see if there are any other errors ?

Comment: no error, no response. that's why i dont know whether it works or not

Comment: @HiPownedBi instead of alert try `console.log('')` in both the functions, just to make sure that the functions are hit.